# How does a webpage detects how long you are staying on that page and how to send fake time details(if possible) to that webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, captcha

I just want to know how does a website tracks that how much time I spend on that particular webpage. Maybe sometimes captcha(specially in form pages) are involved in detecting the time.

I want to know how it's done?

And is there any way to send fake time details.

Some webpages needs to wait on their page for some seconds before proceeding. I just want to bypass that.

Is it possible?

Comment: Generally, Javascript timers or the `setTimeout()` function are used, which runs entirely inside your browser. You're not transmitting any timing information over the wire, since the code typically runs on your computer.

Comment: However, you are somewhat correct that the information is generally accessible to webmasters; trackers like Google Analytics can track how long you spend on a specific page, by recording when you enter the page and when you leave. Similar approaches are possible in Javascript by intercepting navigation events and recording the system time (via `new Date()` or the like) to the server.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja can I see the code using inspect element or it's hidden. Can you give me an example of that type of code.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja if any webpage needs me to stay there for some seconds and I cannot proceed before that time Then is it done using google Analytics. Is google analytics responsible for that??

Comment: You can take a look at the Google Analytics script yourself, if you want. Go to a site running Google Analytics (pretty much all of them do) and look in the Developer Tool for the downloaded resource `analytics.js`. Be warned, it's obfuscated. For info on how it works, [read here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/?hl=en)

Comment: No, forcing you to wait on a webpage is not done using Google Analytics.

Comment: You'll have to look at the specific webpage for the script that executes the redirect to the desired page, and pull out the appropriate URL and redirect to it manually. Look for the `setTimeout` function when digging through the Javascript on the page.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Okay I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Why haven't you compiled all this info into an answer? It answers the question.

Comment: @durron597 I haven't because I feel this is too open-ended of a question. I don't know how the site in question works, and he hasn't posted a link to it. If I answer something based on intuition and it doesn't work for the site he wants to circumvent, then it's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know how does a website tracks that how much time I
>   spend on that particular webpage.

See [Window.performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance)

```
performance.now()
```

Comment: Is this available on all browsers?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance#Browser_compatibility